# Dynamic Blank Row in Excel Without VBA Script

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dynamic, spreadsheet

I'm looking for a way to dynamically keep a blank row between two data sets in Excel, without the use of a VBA Script. Is this possible? Let me explain...

The first data set has a formula in A4 that outputs Date, Pursuit Lead, Project Name and Est. Amount. This first data set is dynamic in that it is pulling in data **from a table in another tab**, and so the amount of rows output from this formula may increase or decrease. This first data set happens to end in row 7.

There is a second data set that I want to dynamically move up or down with a blank row just above it (and below the first data set), depending upon the length of the first data set. Having the 2nd data set being static will present problems due to the uncertainty of the size of the first data set. To clarify, the title of the second data set, the headers, and the data underneath it would all need to move up or down dynamically under that blank row, depending upon the output size of the first data set.

**Is there a way to either use OFFSET or another function to always have a blank row underneath the first data set, and to move the second data set up or down, depending upon the output size of the first data set?**

*Theoretically, I'm guessing that instead of an actual blank row, that there could be text colored white that could be inserted as a helper instead of a real blank row, if that would aid in providing a solution.*

[Keep in mind that though this file is shared from Google Drive as a Google Sheets file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rXUQ5F710YVaetjz6T0fJ2gPG3UFwv_5M-rPOYw1nc0/edit?usp=sharing), the data lives in Excel and thus, the solution must work for Microsoft Excel.

I've tried a few things, and have looked on Stack Overflow, but have yet to find a place to start from.

Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: If you have Excel 365 look for `VSTACK`

Answer (score 0):

When I needed to place multiple dynamic tables in one worksheet, I used datatables. In your case, you may need to create four tables - one for each summary and one for each data. In this way, it will also be possible to simplify summary formulas. For example - for monthly sum and count you can use respectively:

```
=SUM(Table2[Est. Amount])
```

and

```
=COUNTA(Table2[Date])
```

[image]

Comment: not sure if that's going to work since the data is being pulled in from a table in another tab. I think I failed to mention that in my original post, so I've updated it with that information.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to provide [this solution here from Hazem Hassan](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/hazemhassandrexcel_excel-hazemabrhassan-drabrexcel-activity-7166755147094605824-v-KO?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_desktop), in case anyone might want to see it. All credit to Hazem Hassan for this solution.

[image]

Use GROUPBY in #excel to add Blank Rows/Cols After Each Group

**to add blank Rows:**

```
=LET(
    a, GROUPBY(B4:D13, E4:F13, SUM, , 2),
    DROP(IF(BYROW(--(a = ""), SUM), "", a), -2)
)
```

**to add blank Cols:**

```
=TRANSPOSE(
    LET(
        a, GROUPBY(B4:D13, E4:F13, SUM, , 2),
        DROP(IF(BYROW(--(a = ""), SUM), "", a), -2)
    )
)
```